# Recursive function for LCM in C++ using multiple numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, numbers, lcm

Please can someone help me with the recursive function to find the LCM of an array of ints.
The function call will be: `int LCM(int * arr, int length){}`
Please can someone help me.

Comment: Yes, they will all be natural counting numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have marked this as C++.  Here is one possible C++ way of how to do this, with std::vector.

```
   class T435_t
   {
   private:
      std::vector<int> iVec;

      void show(std::string label)
         {
            std::cout << label << std::endl;
            for (auto iv : iVec)
               std::cout << " iVec " << std::setw(6) << iv << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
         }

   public:

      T435_t() // : std::vector<int> iVec - default ctor ok
         {
         }

      ~T435_t() {  }

      int exec()
         {
            // test data 
            iVec.push_back(5);
            iVec.push_back(10);
            iVec.push_back(15);
            iVec.push_back(20);
            iVec.push_back(25);

            show("\n ----    ---");

            int retVal = LCM(1); // start tmp at 1

            std::cout << " LCM   " << std::setw(6) << retVal << std::endl;

            return(0);
         }

   private:

      inline bool componentOf (int tmp)
         {
            size_t count = 0;
            for (auto iv : iVec)
            {
               if (0 == (tmp % iv))
                  ++count;  // how many elements of vec are component
            }
            return (count == iVec.size()); // when all are
         }

      // recursion 
      int LCM(int tmp)
         {
            if (componentOf(tmp)) // recursion termination clause
               return (tmp); 

            return (LCM (++tmp)); // probably tail recursion with -O3
         }
   };


int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   std::cout << "argc: " << argc << std::endl;
   for (int i=0; i<argc; i+=1) std::cout << argv[i] << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;

   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
   std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

   T435_t t435;  // C++ uses classes!
   int retVal = t435.exec();  

   std::cout << "\nFINI " << std::endl;
   return(retVal);
}
```

Output:

```
 ----    ---
 iVec      5
 iVec     10
 iVec     15
 iVec     20
 iVec     25

 LCM      300
```

Output with 5 and 6 coded into iVec

```
----    ---
iVec      5
iVec      6

LCM       30
```

Comment: Notice how the use of vector simplifies the code ... counting and insert index all taken care of for you.

Comment: Notice how use of vector and "for (auto iv : iVec)" simplifies the scanning of the contents of iVec, for both "show()" and method "componentOf()".

Comment: Notice how the recursive code "LCM()" has full access to any data attribute of the class ... for instance, I did not need to pass the 'array' ptr and length thru the recursion, LCM() simply accessed the instances  iVec.  I also did not need to pass 'tmp' thru the recursion, but I thought it looked more familiar with it.

Answer (score -1):

```
int lcm(int a,int b){

   static int temp = 1;

    if(temp % b == 0 && temp % a == 0)
         return temp;
    temp++;
    lcm(a,b);

   return temp;
}
```

Comment: How would i then convert this so that it will accept an array of ints where a is?